# @ContextConfiguration with SpringExtension does not detect explicitly defined @Bean

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit

I am using JUnit5 with `SpringExtension`. But for reason the first test succeeds while the second one fail

Can anyone tell me why this fails?

```java
package com.acme;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ConfigurationTest.Config.class)
public class ConfigurationTest {
  @Test
  void explicitContextTest() {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext =
        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
    assertThat(applicationContext.getBean(Skeleton.class)).isNotNull();
  }

  @Test
  void contextConfigInjectionTest(Skeleton skeleton) {
    assertThat(skeleton).isNotNull();
  }

  @Configuration
  static class Config {
    @Bean
    Skeleton skeleton() {
      return new SkeletonImpl();
    }
  }

  interface Skeleton {
  }

  static class SkeletonImpl implements Skeleton {
  }
}
```

PS: If I add `@ComponentScan` at `Config` class level, the second test also succeed. The question is more along the lines of why spring test is not able to detect explicitly defined beans unless I ask it to scan explicitly

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have to specify `@Autowired` for the test parameter for spring extension to kick in

I just tried it. This works

```java
package com.acme;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ConfigurationTest.Config.class)
public class ConfigurationTest {
  @Test
  void explicitContextTest() {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext =
        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
    assertThat(applicationContext.getBean(Skeleton.class)).isNotNull();
  }

  @Test
  void contextConfigInjectionTest(@Autowired Skeleton skeleton) {
    assertThat(skeleton).isNotNull();
  }

  @Configuration
  static class Config {
    @Bean
    Skeleton skeleton() {
      return new SkeletonImpl();
    }
  }

  interface Skeleton {
  }

  static class SkeletonImpl implements Skeleton {
  }
}
```

As per the Spring extension implementation, spring expects either `@Autowired`/`@Qualifier`/`@Value` to be present. Only then spring resolve the test parameters against the `ApplicationContext`. Else, it simply does not resolve

Ref:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/0ad9349d84a725dc37499bcb0ed2aad0de770c73/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/test/context/junit/jupiter/SpringExtension.java#L156-L163